# CRYSTAL REPORT FOR VISUAL STUDIO 2010 ASP.NET INVALID FILENAME ERROR

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

Hey everybody I am facing this error with crystal report

Server Error in '/' Application.

Invalid file name.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Invalid file name.

```
Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 
[COMException (0x800001fb): Invalid file name.]
   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.ReportClientDocumentClass.Open(Object& DocumentPath, Int32 Options) +0
   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.Open(Object& DocumentPath, Int32 Options) +95
   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened() +270

[CrystalReportsException: Load report failed.]
   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened() +333
   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename, OpenReportMethod openMethod, Int16 parentJob) +876
   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename) +84
   WebPathLab.AgentList.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +524
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207
```

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272

========================
I am Using Visual Studio 2010. Crystal report version is 13.0.2000
I have entered the following line in web.config

```
  <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
```

My crystal report is working fine when I run it by pressing F5 from visual studio 2010.

Directory Structure

Reports/Dataset/ Dataset1.xsd
Reports/rpt/ CrystalReport1.rot
Reports/ AgentList.aspx

Imported Namespaces

```
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.IO
```

CodeBehind

```
Dim reportpath As String = Server.MapPath("rpt/CrystalReport1.rpt")
com.CommandText = "SELECT  idAgent AS ID,AgentName,Add1 AS Address FROM PmAgentMaster"
com.Connection = conPatho
da.SelectCommand = com
dt.Rows.Clear()
If conPatho.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then conPatho.Open()
da.Fill(dt)
conPatho.Close()
Dim ds As New DataSet1()
ds.Tables(0).Merge(dt)
ShowPopUpMsg(reportpath)
Dim rptDoc As New ReportDocument()
rptDoc.Load(reportpath)
rptDoc.SetDataSource(ds)
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc
```

Can anyone help me. Please.

Comment: hAS aNYONE sEEN mY cAPSLOCK kEY?

Answer (score 1):

Try this (note the tilde):

```
Server.MapPath("~/rpt/CrystalReport1.rpt")
```

Comment: Load report failed.
error arise when use Server.MapPath("~/rpt/CrystalReport1.rpt")

My application directroy structure is
~/webpathlab/Forms/Reports/Dataset/ Dataset1.xsd
~/webpathlab/Forms/Reports/rpt/ CrystalReport1.rot
~/webpathlab/Forms/Reports/ AgentList.aspx

Comment: What is reportpath set to after you initialize it.  Is it correct?

Comment: D:\WEBDATA\pathology-software.com\webpathlab\Forms\Reports\rpt\CrystalReport1.rpt
The above path is returning by reportpath which is correct. In server CrystalReport1.rpt is exist there.

Comment: It may be barfing on this directory:  \pathology-software.com\   Can you put the file in non-weird directory and try it?